# Проблема с добавлением данных в EF6

Tags: entity-framework

Использую **EF6.**
В классе контекста БД имеется дженерик-метод:

```
public TEntity InsertOrUpdate<TEntity>(TEntity entityInstance) where TEntity : BaseEntity
        {
            if (entityInstance is IChangable)
            {
                IChangable newInstance = (IChangable)(entityInstance as IChangable).GetNewInstance();
                newInstance.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                newInstance.ModifiedFromId = entityInstance.ID;
                this.Entry<TEntity>(entityInstance).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                this.Entry<TEntity>((TEntity)newInstance).State = EntityState.Added;
                this.SaveChanges();
                return (TEntity)newInstance;
            }
            else
                { 
                    if (entityInstance.ID == default(int))
                    {
                        this.Set<TEntity>().Add(entityInstance);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Entry<TEntity>(entityInstance).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    this.SaveChanges();
                    return entityInstance;
            }

        }
```

Как видите, задача его следующая: если он получил в качестве аргумента объект, реализующий IChangable, то строку для в базе данных изменять не нужно,
нужно создать её копию и поместить новый экземпляр в базу. Но в результате у меня создаётся две строки с изменёнными значениями полей.

Для примера: я вношу изменения, скажем, для пользователя *Пётр Иванов*. Меняю его имя на *Сергей Иванов*. Сущность пользователя реализует IChangable. 
Следовательно, я ожидаю, что *Пётр Иванов* в моей базе так и останется Петром Ивановым, а в базу **добавится** новая строка "Сергей Иванов", где в поле modifiedFromID
добавится значение ID исходной строки. Вместо этого в моей базе появляется два Сергея. Т.е. значения полей изменяются и у исходной строки и у новой.

Пример кода, в котором я вызываю метод:

```
    AppEnvironment.SetContextType(new RealContextNinjectModule());
    AppEnvironment.Authorize("Admin", "password", true);

    var con = new AppEnvironment.GetContext();

    var userInstance = f.GetUserByLastName("Иванов").Single();
    userInstance.FirstName = "Сергей";
    con.CreateOrUpdateEntity(userInstance);
```

Подскажите, как мне добиться от метода желаемого поведения. Заранее извиняюсь, если технически неграмотно описал ситуацию. Спасибо.

**Обновлено:**

Код класса сущности:

```
public class User : PersonEntity
{
   public string Position { get; set; }
   public User(string lastName, string firstName, string patronymic, string position) : base(lastName,firstName,patronymic)
   {
       this.Position = position;
   }

   public override object GetNewInstance()
   {
      return new User(LastName, FirstName, Patronymic, Position);
   }

}
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код реализации метода `GetNewInstance()`. Он верно работает?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, взгляните.

Comment: PersonEntity is IChangable?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, да, базовый класс реализует этот интерфейс.

Comment: @klutch1991 проверьте в дебаге значения и адреса `entityInstance` и `newInstance` перед сохранением. PS: то что вы делаете с архитектурной точки зрения огромный костыль. Вам нужно было реализовать `Event Sourcing`, желательно с `CQRS`, желательно с `DDD`, если конечно вы пишете серьезный проект и находитесь на начальных стадиях.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, а можете, если не сложно, краткий пример в ответе написать? Честно говоря, с трудом представляю, о чём вы.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, ну или ссылки на источники, где можно почитать об этом.

Comment: @klutch1991 например вот: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146429/